# FileSystemWatcher not monitoring local user folder or temporary internet files folder in Vista (64bit)

Tags: c#, windows-vista, filesystemwatcher

I wrote a test program to monitor my Picture folder which points to c:\users[username]\Pictures and temporary internet files folder for the same user. This is program works perfectly fine if I change the folder to other location like d:\persona_pics.
Any idea why events are not being raised when I set the mentioned folder to monitor?

here is the code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //FileSystemWatcher myJpegFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\low\content.ie5\"); 
            FileSystemWatcher myJpegFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\[username]\Pictures\ "); 

            myJpegFileWatcher.Filter = "*.jpg";
            myJpegFileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(myJpegFileWatcher_Created);
            myJpegFileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(myJpegFileWatcher_Changed);
            myJpegFileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            myJpegFileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime;

            myJpegFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.Read();

        }

        static void myJpegFileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo duplicateFile = new FileInfo(@e.FullPath);
            bool flag = true;

            while (flag)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (duplicateFile.Length > 20000)
                    {
                        duplicateFile.CopyTo(@"d:\pics\spy\ " + e.Name);
                        flag = false;
                        StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(@"d:\pics\log.txt", true);
                        fs.WriteLine("file is being copied:{0}, Size={1}", e.FullPath, duplicateFile.Length);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(@"d:\pics\log.txt", true);
                        fs.WriteLine("file is not being copied:{0}, Size={1}", e.FullPath, duplicateFile.Length);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //   
                }
            }

        }

        static void myJpegFileWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo duplicateFile = new FileInfo(@e.FullPath);
            bool flag = true;

            while (flag)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (duplicateFile.Length > 20000)
                    {
                        duplicateFile.CopyTo(@"d:\pics\spy\ " + e.Name);
                        flag = false;
                        StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(@"d:\pics\log.txt", true);
                        fs.WriteLine("file is being copied:{0}, Size={1}", e.FullPath, duplicateFile.Length);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //   
                }
            }



        }
    }
```

**Working code..**

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        FileSystemWatcher myJpegFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\[user]\Pictures\"); 

        myJpegFileWatcher.Filter = "*.jpg";

        myJpegFileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(myJpegFileWatcher_Changed);

        myJpegFileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

        myJpegFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.Read();

    }

    static void myJpegFileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo duplicateFile = new FileInfo(@e.FullPath);
        bool flag = true;

        while (flag)
        {
            try
            {
                if (duplicateFile.Exists)
                {

                    if (duplicateFile.Length > 20000)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            duplicateFile.CopyTo(@"d:\pics\spy\" + e.Name,true);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(@"d:\pics\log.txt", true);
                            fs.WriteLine("Error Inside copying:{0}", ex.Message);
                            fs.Close(); 
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            flag = false;
                            StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(@"d:\pics\log.txt", true);
                            fs.WriteLine("file is being copied:{0}, Size={1}", e.FullPath, duplicateFile.Length);
                            fs.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(@"d:\pics\log.txt", true);
                        fs.WriteLine("file is not being copied:{0}, Size={1}", e.FullPath, duplicateFile.Length);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(@"d:\pics\log.txt", true);
                fs.WriteLine("Error:{0}", ex.Message);
                fs.Close(); 
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you checked folder permissions?

Comment: Is it possibly being virtualized by Vista/Win7? What happens when you run the program elevated?

Comment: Folder permissions were readonly on c:\users which I removed and that didnt help.

Dont want to run virtual PC. I think there should be some way to access all system folder like other folders since this program runs perfect on other folders, so its a permission issue. I even tried runing as administrator and 32 bit application.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that tool really helped. I put try catch around my code to narrow down what's the issue is. now it is working in mypicture folder. Although when I tried Filemon, I got the message that processmon is the lates and should be used instead. Anyway, thanks for the help. Much appreciated. I have included the working code above just incase someone may find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run FileMon (SysInternals tool available through MSDN). It will show you what your code actually does on the file system. Then you might be able to find out why or what exactly behaves differently when you point your code to "My Pictures" etc.